# Trouble building JAR with Spring dependencies for Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, build.gradle

I have a Spring application that I want to Dockerize. I created the Docker image and tried running it, but it won't start. It seems it can't find my dependencies. This works totally fine locally on my machine, but I'm having trouble running it in Docker.

The error I receive when running the image:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

`App.java`:

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use a base image with a Java runtime environment
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the JAR file into the container
COPY app/build/libs/fraud-detection-service-1.0.jar .

# Set the command to run your application
CMD ["java", "-cp", "fraud-detection-service-1.0.jar", "com.App"]
```

Here is my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    id("jacoco")
    id("scala")
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "1.4.32"
}

group = "com"
version = "1.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://jitpack.io")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient")
    implementation("com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema:1.11.1")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6")

    testImplementation("io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.7.0")
    testImplementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.0")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2")
    testImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.31.0")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.12.4")
    testImplementation("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9")
    testImplementation("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.9")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.java.server.App"
    }
}

... removed some test configuration ...


val jarVersion: String by project
tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.App"
    }
    archiveFileName.set("fraud-detection-service-$version.jar")
}
```

Other people have had this problem before, which seems to be a dependency-related issue, but none of the other suggestions have worked for me.

Some have suggested using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, which didn't seem to work for me (or maybe I'm not implementing it properly). Others have proposed upgrading/downgrading my Spring Boot version as well.

Comment: I think there is nothing to do with Docker here, you can just run your jar/war by issuing 'java -jar <file_name>', am sure you can replicate this issue without Docker in your local. To me its looking more like a packaging issue in your build file. May be plugin misconfiguration. Surely nothing related to Docker. May be its working fine in your IDE, thats why you have a feeling like its working fine in your local. Try running in local from the generated artefact.

Comment: Remove the jar tasks. You shold use the Spring Boot plugin to create the jar, which it will automatically do if you do `gradlew build`, your `jar` task configuration is messing things up for this. Finally use `-jar` to run your jar not `-cp` `CMD ["java", "-jar", "fraud-detection-service-1.0.jar"]` the jar itself is executable and you are bypassing this again.